On Full Hilbert C* module
Suppose $({H},p, X)$ be a full continuous Hilbert bundle over a locally compact space $X$, where $p$ denotes the projection map from the bundle space ${H}$ to $X$. Let $\Gamma_{0}$ denotes the continuous sections vanishing at infinity. It forms a Hilbert $C_{0}(X)$-module. Whether $\Gamma_{0}$ is a full Hilbert module?
A Hilbert bundle is full when for each $h \in H$, there exist a continuous section $t$ such that $t(p(h))=h$.

You should also include the definition of fullness for Hilbert modules as well. Regardless, as is, the trivial bundle $H = X \times {0}$ is an easy counterexample.

(And if you require fibers to be nonzero everywhere, then this is obviously true. In that case fullness of $X$ easily implies some inner products of elements of $\Gamma_0$ do not vanish at any given point in $X$, which is clearly enough to imply density by Stone-Weierstrass.)

Yes Iam assuming each fibers non zero.

Recall that a Hilbert $A$-module $\Gamma_0$ is full iff the closed linear span $I_{\Gamma_0}$ of $\langle x, y\rangle_A$ for $x, y \in \Gamma_0$ is the entirety of $A$. $I_{\Gamma_0}$ is always an ideal, and in our case $A = C_0(X)$, so it suffices to verify $I_{\Gamma_0}$ vanishes nowhere, i.e., it suffices to show, for any $\omega \in X$, there exists $x, y \in \Gamma_0$ s.t. $[\langle x, y \rangle_{C_0(X)}](\omega) \neq 0$. Since the fibers are all nonzero, there exists $h \in H$ s.t. $h \neq 0$ and $p(h) = \omega$. Since $H$ is full, there exists a continuous section $t: X \to H$ s.t. $t(\omega) = h$. To change it to a continuous section that vanishes at infinity, we simply take a compactly supported continuous $f: X \to \mathbb{C}$ s.t. $f(\omega) = 1$. Then $x = ft: X \to H$ is a compactly supported section, whence it belongs to $\Gamma_0$. And, $[\langle x, x\rangle_{C_0(X)}](\omega) = \langle x(\omega), x(\omega)\rangle_H = \langle h, h\rangle_H \neq 0$.

Thank you for the answer

@KNSRIDHARANNAMBOODIRI Consider accepting the answer if you find it satisfactory.
